# Shortest Path, No Left Turns, Printing Path

Tags: c++, graph, shortest-path

I'm doing a project where I need to find the shortest path from a single source to a single destination. I can only take right turns, so there are times where I need to make three right turns instead of a left. I've got the algorithm down already (I think), but I'm having a problem printing the path taken afterward. I'm keeping a came-from pointer on each tile, but when I start at the end and follow the came-from pointers, the times where three rights were taken cause a loop because the came-from pointer gets overridden by the newer one. How can I recognize this loop pattern and get back on track to print the full path?

Here is my backTracker class

```
class backTracker {
    int rows;
    int cols;
    tile** map;
    tile* start;
    tile* end;
    int rightTurns;
    int loopTracker;
    bool done;
    int** visits;
    MyStack visited;
    public:
    backTracker(int inRows, int inCols, tile** inMap, tile* inStart,
                                                tile* inEnd, int** &inVisits) {
            rows = inRows;
            cols = inCols;
            map = inMap;
            start = inStart;
            end = inEnd;
            rightTurns = 0;
            loopTracker = 0;
            done = false;
            visits = inVisits;
    }
    void findPath() {
        backTrack(start);
    }
    private:
    void backTrack(tile* currTile) {
        if (currTile == end || done) {
            cout << "end found" << endl;
            done = true;
            return;
        }
        else if (promising(currTile)) {
            //if it's the start tile, check all directions
            if (currTile->cameFrom == 0) {
                tile* next;
                int cRow = currTile->row;
                int cCol = currTile->col;
                if (cRow != 0) {
                    next = &map[cRow-1][cCol];
                    next->cameFrom = currTile;
                    next->directionFrom = 'N';
                    backTrack(next);
                }
                if (cRow != rows - 1) {
                    next = &map[cRow+1][cCol];
                    next->cameFrom = currTile;
                    next->directionFrom = 'S';
                    backTrack(next);
                }
                if (cCol != cols - 1) {
                    next = &map[cRow][cCol+1];
                    next->cameFrom = currTile;
                    next->directionFrom = 'E';
                    backTrack(next);
                }
                if (cCol != 0) {
                    next = &map[cRow][cCol-1];
                    next->cameFrom = currTile;
                    next->directionFrom = 'W';
                    backTrack(next);
                }
            }
            //otherwise check straight and right
            else {
                    currTile->straight = 0; //the tile in the straight direction
                    currTile->right = 0;//the tile to the right of the straight tile
                    //easier to read
                    int row = currTile->row;
                    int col = currTile->col;
                    bool good = false;
                    //find the straight and right tiles depending on current
                    //direction, also check if the tile has been visited from
                    //that direction already
                    if (currTile->directionFrom == 'N') {
                        if (col != cols - 1) {
                            if (map[row][col+1].directionFrom != 'E') {
                                currTile->right = &map[row][col+1];
                                currTile->right->directionFrom = 'E';
                                good = true;
                                tile* right = currTile->right;
                                right->cameFrom = currTile;
                                backTrack(right);
                            }
                        }
                        if (row != 0) {
                            //if it hasn't already been visited from this direction
                            if (map[row-1][col].directionFrom != 'N') {
                                currTile->straight = &map[row-1][col];
                                good = true;
                                tile* str = currTile->straight;
                                str->cameFrom = currTile;
                                //going straight so direction is the same
                                str->directionFrom = currTile->directionFrom;
                                backTrack(str);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (currTile->directionFrom == 'W') {
                        if (row != 0) {
                            if (map[row-1][col].directionFrom != 'N') {
                                currTile->right = &map[row-1][col];
                                currTile->right->directionFrom = 'N';
                                good = true;
                                tile* right = currTile->right;
                                right->cameFrom = currTile;
                                backTrack(right);
                            }
                        }
                        if (col != 0) {
                            if (map[row][col-1].directionFrom != 'W') {
                                currTile->straight = &map[row][col-1];
                                good = true;
                                tile* str = currTile->straight;
                                str->cameFrom = currTile;
                                //going straight so direction is the same
                                str->directionFrom = currTile->directionFrom;
                                backTrack(str);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (currTile->directionFrom == 'S') {
                        if (col != 0) {
                            if (map[row][col-1].directionFrom != 'W') {
                                currTile->right = &map[row][col-1];
                                currTile->right->directionFrom = 'W';
                                good = true;
                                tile* right = currTile->right;
                                right->cameFrom = currTile;
                                backTrack(right);
                            }
                        }
                            if (row != rows - 1) {
                            if (map[row+1][col].directionFrom != 'S') {
                                currTile->straight = &map[row+1][col];
                                good = true;
                                tile* str = currTile->straight;
                                str->cameFrom = currTile;
                                //going straight so direction is the same
                                str->directionFrom = currTile->directionFrom;
                                backTrack(str);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (currTile->directionFrom == 'E'){
                        if (row != row - 1) {
                            if (map[row+1][col].directionFrom != 'S') {
                                currTile->right = &map[row+1][col];
                                currTile->right->directionFrom = 'S';
                                good = true;
                                tile* right = currTile->right;
                                right->cameFrom = currTile;
                                backTrack(right);
                            }
                        }
                        if (col != cols - 1) {
                            if (map[row][col+1].directionFrom != 'E') {
                                currTile->straight = &map[row][col+1];
                                good = true;
                                tile* str = currTile->straight;
                                str->cameFrom = currTile;
                                //going straight so direction is the same
                                str->directionFrom = currTile->directionFrom;
                                backTrack(str);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

            }

        }
        //checks for walls
        bool promising(tile* currTile) {
            if (currTile->type == WALL) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Any concrete information you can give us? An image? Code? A paper describing the question?

Comment: It's for a class, and the policy is not to post code publicly anywhere... I'm using a backtracking algorithm to find the path, and the environment is just a grid of letters, 'X' being a wall '.' being a valid space to move to. Sorry I can't give you more info.

Comment: I think you should just keep an array of the tiles travelled to, not rely on the tiles to keep that information. You won't have any ambiguity there.

Comment: How would I distinguish tiles in the path from tiles that were simply visited?

Comment: Store only the coordinates of the tiles you are trying to get to.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really following you. I don't know the coordinates I'm trying to get to, I'm just doing a DFS until the goal tile is found.

Comment: Oh, whoops, sorry. I missed that part. Without any code or details, it'll be hard to get help here.

Comment: The bug in my code is after the path-finding algorithm completes. I have an iterator (just a pointer to a tile) which I initialize to the goal tile. I then loop through, changing the tile char to 'p' for path taken, and updating the iterator to the tile's cameFrom member. In my algorithm, while examining a current tile, I find the tile in the straight direction and the tile in the right direction (depending on what direction was taken to get to the tile being examined), set the cameFrom member of those two tiles to the current tile, then check those two tiles recursively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store several (at most four) pieces of information in each cell. I don't know how you search your matrix, but I would do it with some kind of breadth-first algorithm that would try to find a path from all four directions to each cell. Every cell must store the number of steps that must be taken to reach that cell from all four directions. This path build is stopped once the destination is reached. To recreate the path then go backwards and iteratively find neighboring cell that is one step less away from destination from current cell.

Comment: Right now I'm using a backtracking algorithm (required by the project spec) that does a depth-first search and only checks the tile straight ahead and to the right, pruning the left and backwards directions.

Comment: I guess the same reasoning applies for depth-first too. You need extra room to store extra information, because you only have room for one information per cell.

Comment: What type of information would be helpful to store besides cameFrom?

Comment: You need a sort of stack for each cell, with values cameFrom1, cameFrom2, cameFrom3. When you visit a cell you find out where to go next, and then remove that value from stack. When you visit the cell next time some other value will await you. Max stack size is 3, I think.

Comment: But wait, if you do depth-first then you already have the full path. It's created during recursion. Cells do not have to have any visiting information. All you need is some list or vector where you push next cell, and pop current when backtracking.